# Why do I get an exception parsing a valid UTC date with GSON?

Tags: android, gson

On Android trying to parse this date string:
`2017-02-21T00:45:03-05:00`
with GSON 2.8.0 using the UtcDateTypeAdapter I get an exception:

`Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2017-02-21T00:45:03-05:00']: null (at offset 0)
at com.google.gson.typeadapters.UtcDateTypeAdapter.read(UtcDateTypeAdapter.java:66)
at com.google.gson.typeadapters.UtcDateTypeAdapter.read(UtcDateTypeAdapter.java:39)
...`

Yet clearly the date is in a valid format.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the key things were that I was using a *non* EN (ie. AR) Locale on older (API < 23) versions of Android and the way timezone IDs are handled under that Locale.

The offending code is:

`TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneId);
if (!timezone.getID().equals(timezoneId)) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}`

As on older versions of Android the values in the above code for timezone.getID() vs timezoneId are:
`GMT-٠٥:٠٠` vs `GMT-05:00`